# Rails 4: Parent has_one Child with a specific related ChildType

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-one, scopes

I have a `Parent` who has many `Children`, but only one `Firstborn`.  The `Firstborn` is a `Child` with a related `ChildType` of "firstborn".

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
  has_one :firstborn, -> { includes(:child_type).references(:child_type).where("child_type.name = ?", "firstborn") }, class_name: "Child"
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :child_type
end

class ChildType
  has_many :children
end
```

The following code does **not** work:

```
parent = Parent.find(1)      # => <parent object>
firstborn = parent.firstborn # => nil
```

The end goal is being able to retrieve all Parents and Firstborn children in 1 query.

```
parents_and_firstborn = Parent.includes(:firstborn)
```

I'm looking for a solution that only executes 1 query and retrieves the `Parent` and related `Firstborn` children.

I've reviewed the Rails 4.0.2 API docs about `has_one`, but none of their examples
span across multiple tables like what I'm trying to do.

**Update: 2014-10-16 14:40**

The following "works" but I don't know why:

`parent = Parent.includes(:firstborn).find(1) # => <parent with firstborn>`

Why can I not retrieve the `firstborn` AFTER I have retrieved the `Parent`, but if I `includes(...)` it in the original query it returns it?

**Solution: 2014-10-16 14:50**

I had an `attr_accessor :firstborn` still stuck in the `Parent` model from previous attempts as solving this problem.  When I removed that unused code, the `has_one :firstborn ...` code worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct(ish) as is, you should debug the SQL being executed.

I'd actually question the merit of the ChildType table from what I see here. You schema seems overly complicated. Why don't you use a first_born bool?

Comment: I would love to use an alternate schema design...however, I'm working with a legacy system and I have no ability to change it.  Trust me, I've tried for a few months because of this issue and many, many others. For the particular issue, there will be multiple ChildTypes that I may need to query/filter on.

Comment: If you show the SQL being returned on both cases; we might have better luck helping you debug.

Comment: Oh...I found the problem. I feel stupid now!  While I was working on this problem, I had created an `attr_accessor :firstborn` before I decided to go with a `has_one` association.  That accessor method was what was returning `nil`.  Once I removed that, the above code actually did work as expected. I hate legacy systems!

Comment: Ooof! Yay rubber ducking. Good luck with your legacy system; I've handled a couple of those before, they can be frustrating.